# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{\sideset{^{3n}}{_n} C}{\sideset{^{2n}}{_n} C})^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{\sideset{^{3n}}{_n} C}{\sideset{^{2n}}{_n} C})^{\frac{1}{n}}$

---

Let $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{\sideset{^{3n}}{_n} C}{\sideset{^{2n}}{_n} C})^{\frac{1}{n}}$
$\log L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\frac{(3n)!(n!)(n!)}{(2n)!(n)!(2n)!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\frac{(3n)!(n)!}{(2n)!(2n)!}$
$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\frac{(3n)(3n-1)(3n-2)...(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)....(n+2)(n+1)}$
There are $n$ terms in the numerator and $n$ terms in the denominator.
The starting ratios $\frac{3n}{2n},\frac{3n-1}{2n-1},\frac{3n-2}{2n-2}$ are tending to $\frac{3}{2}$ as $n$ is tending to $\infty$ but the last,second last,third last ...ratios are tending to $2$ as $n$ is tending to $\infty$.
I am not sure what to do?I am stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratio is equal to

$$\frac{(3 n)! (n!)}{(2 n)!^2 } $$

which, by Stirling's approximation, is approximately

$$\frac{(3 n)^{3 n} e^{-3 n} \sqrt{2 \pi 3 n}\, n^n e^{-n} \sqrt{2 \pi n}}{(2 n)^{4 n} e^{-4 n} (2 \pi 2 n)}  = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \left (\frac{27}{16} \right )^n$$

Thus, the limit in question is $27/16 = 3^3/2^4$.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote : $$A_n=\log\frac{(3n)!(n)!}{(2n)!(2n)!}=\log(3n!)+\log(n!)-2\log(2n!)$$ Now, use [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) 
$$\log(p!)=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log
   \left(p\right)\right)+\frac{1}{12
   p}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^{5/2}\right)$$ which makes $$A_n=n (3 \log (3)-4 \log (2))+\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{36
   n}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2}\right)$$